# AWS AmazonMQ user configuration Attribute 'Id' does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-mq

I have problems creating AmazonMQ with custom configuration. I followed aws [complex example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-amazonmq-broker.html#aws-resource-amazonmq-broker--examples--Complex_Amazon_MQ_Broker--yaml) in docs in a way:

```
  amazonMq:
    Type: "AWS::AmazonMQ::Broker"
    Properties:
      Configuration:
        Id: !GetAtt amazonMqConf.Id
        Revision: !GetAtt amazonMqConf.Revision
      # ... the rest of Broker attributes ... #

  amazonMqConf:
    Type: AWS::AmazonMQ::Configuration
    Properties:
      Data: ""
      # ... the rest of Config attributes ... #
```

And I ended up getting error:

> Attribute 'Id' does not exist

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of trial-error it showed up that [return values documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-amazonmq-configuration.html#aws-resource-amazonmq-configuration-return-values) is not correct and there is no such attribute at `Id`. What helped is replacing

```
!GetAtt amazonMqConf.Id
```

with

```
!Ref amazonMqConf
```

since default (Ref) returns same value as Id does.